# Please help me on sort in c or c++

Tags: c++, c, arrays, sorting

I have an array(2D) in c:

80|100|70|50|120

A|C|D|F|K

I need to sort it into this :

50|70|80|100|120

F|D|A|C|K

I am using c or c++. please help me.

thanks.

Comment: Please provide what you have tried!!

Comment: In C `qsort` should be up to the task.

Comment: How is this:
A|C|D|F|K
being sorted to 
F|D|A|C|K ?

Comment: @user1944429 The numbers are the keys, they're sorted in ascending order, then the values corresponding to them (the letters) are reorganized according to that order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++:

```
std::vector<int> keys;
std::vector<char> values;
std::map<int, char> kvtable;

keys.push_back(80);
values.push_back('A');

keys.push_back(100);
values.push_back('C');

keys.push_back(70);
values.push_back('D');

keys.push_back(50);
values.push_back('F');

keys.push_back(120);
values.push_back('K');

int i;
for (i = 0; i < keys.size(); i++) {
    kvtable[keys[i]] = values[i];
}

std::sort(keys.begin(), keys.end());

for (i = 0; i < keys.size(); i++) {
    std::cout << keys[i] << " = " << kvtable[keys[i]] << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You also have [`qsort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/qsort), [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) with examples of usage.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you should do is to create a utility 1-D array of pointers into the 1st dimension of your array and provide a custom comparison function to sort the utility array. Then you can do pointer math to create a sorted copy of the array (and overwrite the original array if necessary using memcpy)

```
static int ARRAY_LEN = 5;

int[2][ARRAY_LEN] origArray;
int*[ARRAY_LEN] pointerArray;

for(int i = 0; i < ARRAY_LEN; i++){
    pointerArray[i] = &origArray[0][i];  //create the pointer array
}

qsort(pointerArray, ARRAY_LEN, sizeof(int*), compar); //sort the pointer array

/*We need to define the comparison function */
int compar ( const void * elem1, const void * elem2 ){
    return **(int**)elem1 - **(int**)elem2;
} 

int[2][ARRAY_LEN] sortedArray;

for(int i = 0; i < ARRAY_LEN; i++){
    int* curr = pointerArray[i];
    int firstDimValue = *curr; // get the first dimension of the ith element of the sorted array
    int secondDimValue = curr[ARRAY_LEN]; // get the 2nd dimension of the ith element of the sorted array - this works because of the way that 2D arrays are laid out in memory

    sortedArray[0][i] = firstDimValue;
    sortedArray[1][i] = secondDimValue;
}
```

Comment: `int 2nd_dimValue`? Really? Time to fire up the part of the Standard that deals with identifiers.

Comment: ok - are we happy? have I added enough [OH-] to neutralize you? haha

Answer (score 0):

1. Create an array to save the numbers like this:

   int array[5] = {80,100,70,50,120};

2.Create an function to compare two elems:

```
   bool compare(int a,int b)
{
   return a<b; //ASC
}
```

3.Use library function sort() :

```
sort(array,array+5,compare);
```

4.Now the array had been sort by ASC correctly.

Answer (score 0):

And there are so many types of sort like this:

```
void Swap(int &x,int &y)   //not sort, just for swap two elems
{
    int temp;
    temp=x;
    x=y;
    y=temp;
} 

void StraightInsertSort(int elem[],int n) 
{
    int i,j,temp;
    for(i=1;i<n;i++)
    {
        temp=elem[i];
        for(j=i-1;j>=0&&temp>elem[j];j--)
        {
            elem[j+1]=elem[j];
        }
        elem[j+1]=temp;
    }
}

void SimpleSelectSort(int elem[],int n) 
{
    for(int i=0;i<n-1;i++)
    {
        int lowIndex=i;
        for(int j=i+1;j<n;j++)
        {
            if(elem[j]>elem[lowIndex])
            lowIndex=j;
        }
    Swap(elem[i],elem[lowIndex]);
    }
}

void Bubblesort(int elem[],int n)
{
    for(int i=n-1;i>0;i--)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<i;j++)
        {
            if(elem[j]<elem[j+1])
            {
                Swap(elem[j],elem[j+1]); 
            }
        }
    }
}
```